# make permission in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, permissions

I have IIS7, web app is written on ASP.NET 1.1.
I need to see  files and folders in the browser when adress as like http://localhost/MyProject.
Have to make permission for this? or...
so, help me please

UPD. Yes I know it. But when I did this I have this error

```
Line 215:       </root>
Line 216:   </log4net>
Line 217:    <system.webServer>
Line 218:        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
Line 219:    </system.webServer>
```

After That(I read about this pronlrm on interner http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/02/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008.aspx)
I have added to (%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\config\machine.config)
this .
And the error gone.But I still can not browse files.

Answer (score 0):

From IIS click on your website.  Under IIS go to Directory Browsing and click Enable.  See a more complete description on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: @Sergii does your application work otherwise?  Do you have a default document setup?